# How to identify and switch to the frame source in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I have been using the Selenium and Python2.7, on Firefox.

I would like it to work like the following, but I do not know how to write code.

```
Driver.get('https://video-download.online')
Url='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waQlR8W8aTA'
Driver.find_element_by_id("link").send_keys(Url)
Driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
time.sleep(5)
#[Click]lowermost(highest quality) radio button
#[Click]Proceed button
```

Comment: Could you share HTML code here for radio button and proceed button aa well with frame

Comment: Please explain how what you are trying to do differs from what this code does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to get frame locator value in HTML code which is specified in iframes tag. u can move up from where your locator value is existed in HTML code.

This function is suitable:

```
def frame_switch(css_selector):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))
```

If you are just trying to switch to the frame based on the `name` attribute, then you can use this:

```
def frame_switch(name):
  driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name(name))
```

Comment: your reply thanks, but I don't know how to check this site's frame attribute(name,css_selector)...

Comment: I tried this, but don't successed. driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table[id="136-wrapper"]').click())

Comment: and this didn't working, too. driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe")) 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".136-wrapper").click()